# Siri on Volkswagen RCD 310 using Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, siri

How can I get the Volkswagen [RCD 310](http://www.volkswagen.co.uk/technology/entertainment-systems/rcd-310) radio/CD player to work with Siri?

When iPhone is connected to the car using Bluetooth telephone connection and I press and hold its home button, Siri starts, but nothing happens in the car: It does not stop playing music, the alert sound does not play over the car's speakers, and I cannot hear Siri answer my request even though the conversation is displayed on the phone's screen.

Version indication: iPhone 5S with iOS 8.2

[EDIT] when using the phone as Bluetooth media player, when I press the home button to start Siri, I can hear the tone, but I cannot hear the answer to my requests.

Comment: Does calling work over the car's stereo?

Comment: Yes calling and media streaming work!

Comment: When you hold the home button and Siri comes up. Is there a bluetooth symbol at the bottom that allows you to select the output?

Comment: Yes, there's a Bluetooth symbol in the bottom right corner that allows me to select the output. When I tap it, I can see that my car is selected.

Comment: Would love to know if others face the same issue...

Comment: I’m having a similar issue with a 2014 Passat. The Volkswagen technician said it was Apple’s fault citing other vague issues with Apple’s iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

Found a reliable yet cumbersome workaround to have Siri play over the RCD 310 stereo using Bluetooth...

1. Using your car's steering wheel control, disconnect the Bluetooth link to your phone.
2. Open Siri by holding your iPhone's home button.
3. Re-activate the Bluetooth connection from your car to your phone.

Voilà, after a few seconds you can have a dialog with Siri in your car... at least until you leave the Siri screen.

Comment: Notified VW and Apple about this issue using their feedback/contact forms. Will post meaningful updates here...

Comment: Got feedback from Volkswagen AG - Siri is not supported. Their answer in German "Zur Anwendung des Speech Interpretation and Recognition Interface (Siri) der Firma Apple koennen wir leider keine Aussage
treffen, diese Software wird von uns nicht geprueft und unterstuetzt."